# How long do embedded images stay available in draft emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I sometimes embed images in the body of a draft email (images that I upload to Google, and are not hosted on some external website). After a while the image becomes unavailable:

[image]

How long do embedded images stay available in draft emails in Gmail?

I uploaded the image in the body of the email using the form:

[image]

Comment: Are the images uploaded to Google or hosted from an external website?

Comment: @Fogest Uploaded to Google (sorry I thought I had mentioned it, question edited)

Comment: That is odd. I don't see why they would go away. I have no answer to this but it is an interesting question.

Comment: Theoretically should be no time limit. Are you embedding the links to the photos?

Comment: No I uploaded the image in the body of the email using the form: "add an image > My computer" (screenshot added to question)

Comment: Not documented anywhere as far as I can see. Nor have I seen anywhere that someone has experimented to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded images in draft e-mails seem to disappear randomly in Gmail.